# Android LocalSocket won't close when in blocked read

Tags: java, android, sockets

Using localsockets on Android. I have a user reading from another connection. The connection is told to stop reading via closing the socket, closing the input stream, and interrupting it's thread. It doesn't stop attempting to read until the other end shuts down. So, is there anyway to get it to interrupt the read?

Here is a much simplified example of my problem. The problem gets even more awesome when you try to use channels. It will block the interrupt/close request on the thread/channel (respectively).

You should get this log:

```
V/test    ( 4416): bound
V/test    ( 4416): accepted
V/test    ( 4416): stop
V/test    ( 4416): stop exit
V/test    ( 4416): closing
V/test    ( 4416): done reading?
V/test    ( 4416): all closed
```

Class 1:

```
public class Runner1 implements Runnable
{

public static Runner1       me  = null;

public InputStream          in;
public ReadableByteChannel  rb;
LocalSocket                 ls;
public Thread               thisThread;

public Runner1() {
    me = this;
}

@Override
public void run()
{
    thisThread = Thread.currentThread();
    try
    {
        LocalServerSocket lss = new LocalServerSocket(Test2Activity.location);
        ls = lss.accept();
        Log.v("test", "accepted");

        in = ls.getInputStream();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[10];
        in.read(buffer);
        // rb = Channels.newChannel(in);

        // ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(100);
        // rb.read(bb);
        Log.v("test", "done reading?");
        ls.close();
        lss.close();
        Log.v("test", "all closed");
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        Log.v("test", "error1");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void stop()
{
    Log.v("test", "stop");
    try
    {
        // me.rb.close();
        me.in.close();
        me.ls.close();
        // me.ls.shutdownInput();
        // me.ls.shutdownOutput();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        Log.v("test", "error - stop" + e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    me.thisThread.interrupt();

    Log.v("test", "stop exit");
}
}
```

Class2:

```
public class Runner2 implements Runnable
{
@Override
public void run()
{

    try
    {
        sleep(1500);
        LocalSocket ls = new LocalSocket();
        ls.connect(new LocalSocketAddress(Test2Activity.location));
        Log.v("test", "bound");
        WritableByteChannel wc = Channels.newChannel(ls.getOutputStream());
        sleep(3000);
        Runner1.stop();
        sleep(4000);
        Log.v("test", "closing");
        ls.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        Log.v("test", "error" + e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void sleep(int time)
{
    try
    {
        Thread.sleep(time);
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e1)
    {
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best hack I could find to work around this was to set a timeout and check if the socket was closed in another thread.

Sadly, you don't get a TimeoutException when you set a timeout :(

Comment: I don't understand your last sentence. You get a SocketTimeoutException when you have already set a socket read timeout and a new read times out. However setting it after the read has already blocked has no effect on that read.

Answer (score 0):

Just shutdown the socket for input. That will deliver an EOS to the read(). The reading thread should then close the socket itself and exit, which should already be coded.

Comment: The problem is that closing the LocalSocket _does not_ deliver an EOS to the read() (contrary to the behavior of a TCP socket). And closing the InputStream just closed the LocalSocket: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-8.0.0_r17/core/java/android/net/LocalSocketImpl.java#77

Comment: Ah, you probably talked about https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/LocalSocket.html#shutdownInput(). Thanks, it works :)